# What is the different between using TextChangeEvent getText() and TextField getValue() in TextChangeListener

Tags: java, vaadin7, iso

I am new to Vaadin, I try to filter out the data on my table. I add a TextField declared as `isoCode` and add TextChangeListener to it.

When I use the `isoCode.getValue()` to get value as a filter string, it didn't work.

But when I use TextChangeEvent `event.getText()` value it work perfectly. Can someone explain to me tell why?

```
final TextField isoCode = new TextField(); 
isoCode.setInputPrompt("ISO Code");

isoCode.addTextChangeListener(new TextChangeListener(){
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    SimpleStringFilter filter = null;
    @Override
    public void textChange(TextChangeEvent event) {

        /**
         * This code not working
         *
        if(isoCode.getValue().trim().length() > 0){ 
            filter = new SimpleStringFilter("ISO Code", event.getText(),true, false);
            appn0010Form.removeAllContainerFilters();
            appn0010Form.addContainerFilter(filter);
        }
        */


        /**
         * This code is working
         */
        if(event.getText().trim().length() > 0){  
            filter = new SimpleStringFilter("ISO Code", event.getText(),true, false);
            appn0010Form.removeAllContainerFilters();
            appn0010Form.addContainerFilter(filter);
        } 
    } 

});
```

Comment: getText() returns the text within text field. While getValue() will be a processed value for your text. getValue() might defer from text appearing on your textfield, that depends upon implementation.

Comment: Presumably the event delivers the changed text before it has been applied to the component, in case you want to reject or modify it in the listener.

Comment: That's essentially why you use a textChangeListener. event variable listens to text changes so you can perform operations on the fly, whereas the textField itself is not.

Answer (score 0):

`isoCode.getValue()` gives the value of textfield before binding latest value.

Where as `event.getText()` gives you value after binding latest value.

Newly typed value will bind only after blur of Textfield.